# Cordova InAppBrowser Footer is not being displayed in android

Tags: cordova, footer, phonegap, inappbrowser

When I do use cordova InappBrowser plugin V3 with phonegap, the footer is not being displayed in android

I've tried to include the plugin from github (V3.1 dev) but it won't work too.

```
var refBrowser = window.open(myUrl, '_blank', 
'location=no,footer=yes,footercolor=#CC000000,closebuttoncaption=Done,closebuttoncolor=#00FFFF');
```

What should I try to have this footer being displayed?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the **Android version** and the **webview** from the device. What Android version do you have? Can you manually update the webview? Probably newer webview versions have deprecated the footer feature, try in an **emulator** with the old Android 4.4 where the webviews are not upgradeable, or revert to an old webview version.